# Supply extra power to laptop's SATA drive?

Tags: hard-drive, power

I'd like to convert my laptop into a media center. I have an 8TiB HDD that I could plug into it using a SATA extension cable, but I expect that laptop won't have enough power to keep it up. Is there a way to power the HDD externally, other than using a PC PSU? I'd much prefer to connect the HDD via SATA as opposed to USB.

Comment: Connecting the SATA power cable to the HDD is more than enough.  The only question is if the 8TB is the correct size HDD.  Most laptops only accept 2.5" HDDs.  You won't be able to connect a 3.5" HDD to a laptop over SATA

Comment: @Ramhound I have done this before, connect 3.5" drive to laptop motherboard sata port, and external power supply.

Comment: at d33tah I use an old power supply that went with an old ide/sata to usb convertor I had laying around. similar to this....https://www.amazon.com/AGPtek-Drive-Adapter-Converter-External/dp/B00BIE996S/ref=pd_lpo_vtph_147_bs_t_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=KF2DK33KN27ZVSCDHQ6T

Comment: @Moab one of those burned one of my HDDs, so I guess I'd be looking for a different brand. That's the kind of thing I'm looking for though.

Comment: @d33tah yeah it was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to power the HDD externally, other than using a PC PSU?

There is. External HDD docking station with their own power supplies.

External drive connections for 2½ inch drives often ship without PSU, but almost all 3½ inch docks have their own power and need nothing from the laptop.

I used two of these before, one eSATA and USB 2 based, one eSATA and USB 3.1 gen 2 based.

Obviously you want an sata to eSATA cable though, and eSATA is supposed to use higher voltages and run over longer cables (max official SATA cable length is not much). But they saves you the hassle from finding a 20W PC PSU or from running a much more powerful PSU at the really low and inefficient part of its capabilities.

(PSU effectiveness often drops when <10% or >90%).

Comment: Nice! I completely forgot about eSATA. Sounds like this might solve my problem!